# How can I use CSS calc() with inherit?

Tags: css, inheritance, css-animations, css-calc

I would like to use `inherit` with `calc()` like this:

```css
#foo {
  animation-duration: 10s;
}
#foo > .bar {
  animation-duration: calc(inherit + 2s); /* =12s */
}
```

But it don't seem to works.

Is it browsers bug or specs?

Comment: Doesn't work that way ......

Comment: Seems you're out of luck. I tested if you could write `calc(100% + 2s)` but the duration properties don't take percentages. (Only `120%` by itself doesn't work either.) Sorry. Good question though!

Comment: If [Less](http://lesscss.org/) is an option, you can do `@duration:10s; #foo {animation-duration:@duration;} #foo > .bar {animation-duration:@duration + 2s; }`. Of course, that is not exactly the same. There's also [CSS Variables](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables), but that's science fiction for now.

Comment: Hi, did you find a workaround?

Comment: @oren nothink in pure css

Comment: seconds are now supported in calc since Firefox's Quantum update (new Stylo CSS engine)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The `inherit` keyword can only exist alone as a value in a property declaration. It cannot be used with *anything else* as a value, because it's a value in and of itself. This means it cannot be used with functions like `calc()` either. See [CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#value-def-inherit) and [css3-cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#inherit).

So to put it simply, the spec doesn't allow using `inherit` that way.

With this in mind, in order to use an inherited property value as *part* of a child declaration, make a custom property which will be inherited instead:

```css
#foo {
  --duration: 10s;
  animation-duration: var(--duration);
}
#foo > .bar {
  /* --duration is automatically inherited - no need for inherit keyword */
  animation-duration: calc(var(--duration) + 2s); /* =12s */
}
```

Comment: That's right, and it's a shame that 100% isn't an option.

Comment: The accepted answer does not provide a solution to the topic task. How to modify an inherited value with a formula based on the inherited value?

Comment: @meir: Thanks for your comment. This Q&A was written in 2014 when CSS variables weren't yet a thing (as mentioned above), so there *wasn't* a solution to provide. There is now, so I'll add one.